# Taking an integral of e^(another integral) with respect to the limit of integration of (another integral)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How would I go around integrating $$\int_0^\infty \left( \exp{\left(-\int_{k_0}^{k_0+t} (k_1 + k_2s)(k_3+k_4s)^{s} ds \right) } \right) dt \text{,}$$
where $k_i$ are constants?

Is it solvable analytically? If not, is the following integral $$\int_0^n \left( \exp{\left(-\int_{k_0}^{k_0+t} (k_1 + k_2s)(k_3+k_4s)^{s} ds \right) } \right) dt \text{,}$$
where $n \in \mathbb{R}^+$?

I have little idea on how to approach it since I only have a year of calculus behind me. However, I need to evaluate these integrals in any case so what is the best method to do it numerically, if they are not solvable?

**EDIT:** Instead of $k_0+s$ there should be just $s$ in the exponent of $k_3 + k_4s$, I corrected this in the original question.

Comment: Where did you come across this problem?  (Just wondering... it's pretty interesting. `:)`)

Comment: Calculating remaining life expectancy for an individual taking into account changes in death rate in the future. I could go into more detail, but basically the "inside" integral describes the probability of an individual aged $x$ to survive $t$, while the "outside" integral describes remaining life expectancy

Comment: Changed my post to have $k_0$ instead of $x$ so it's less confusing

Comment: @user1136946 I think the first integral may be doable if $k_{4}=0$, but otherwise probably not. If $k_{4}\neq 0$ you'll have something like $\int s^{s}\, ds$ in the inner integral, which has no elementary anti-derivative. I'm going to go out on a limb and say $\exp(\text{that})$ doesn't have one either. If it's doable I'll eat my hat, but you might want to start thinking about the numerical approach. Do you have Mathematica or anything like that?

Comment: Yes, I tried to do this with Mathematica, but it refuses to give me neither a symbolical nor a numerical answer. However, I am not an experienced user so maybe I am doing something wrong. Here's the code I used `Integrate[ E^(-Integrate[(k1 + k2*s)*(k3 + k4*s)^(k0 + s), {s, k0, k0 + t}]), {t, 0, n}]` (for a numerical case I tried the same only with `NIntegrate`, which says that `s = k0 is not a valid limit of integration`). However, if it's not solvable analytically, I will most likely have to implement numerical calculations in Excel, so I have to know the algorithm for that.

Comment: @user1136946 I used (setting $k_{i} = i$ for example) `NIntegrate[
 Exp[-NIntegrate[(1 + 2*s) (3 + 4*s)^s, {s, 0, 0 + t}]], {t, 0, 
  Infinity}]` and it returned `0.3852`. It did complain about invalid limits first but I don't think that actually matters. You definitely have to make sure the net result of `NIntegrate` is a number though, ie. it isn't entirely surprising to me that your command didn't work at all since the result would still be a function of the $k_{i}$, but `NIntegrate` really just wants to give you a number.

Comment: @Mr.G I know that `NIntegrate` is supposed to return a number so I did assign values to $k_i$. Just tried the same today and it worked, no idea what went wrong the previous time. Anyway, since this integral is (most likely) not solvable and Mathematica returns something that looks true, I guess I will try implementing regular trapezoidal method in Excel that first computes the inner integral for a given $t$, then iterate over certain $t$. I would still like someone to show it is not solvable, but, in any case, thanks for the help!

Comment: @user1136946 No problem, but I can tell you right now with certainty that the integral is impossible for a general $n$. That's a  result of my earlier comment that $s^s$ [has no anti-derivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x^x+dx). The issue is that you can *sometimes* circumvent that difficulty when the limits of integration are inifinite via contour integration or other fancy methods. However, if Mathematica returns no analytic answer, it's extremely likely that it's impossible.